# Missing \endcsname inserted. <to be read again> \protect

Tags: missing

I am getting the following error code:

```
./main.aux:113:
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.113 ... find region o

f proportionality}{{1}{10}}
```

Minimum working example (long due to vague error):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[verbose]{placeins}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\begin{document}

%the following section is included as it is around line 113
text $^{241}\textrm{Am}$ text 
\begin{equation}
^{241}_{95}\textrm{Am}\rightarrow ^{237}_{93}\textrm{Np}+^4_2\alpha
\end{equation}

%the following section is included as it is the last bit i worked on
\section{text}

text B$\textrm{F}_3$ text

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{file.png}
\centering
\caption{text B$\textrm{F}_3$ text}
\label{text}
\end{text}

\section{text}

\section{text}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{references}

\section{Appendices}
\subsection{Appendix A}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{text B$\textrm{F}_3$ text}
\label{text}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
data taken from table generator so v.likely correct
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The parts of the code that you posted, by themselves, are correct and working. For we to find out what's going wrong we need a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that produces this same error so we can debug your code.

Comment: Looking at the error message you posted, it seems that the error occurs while reading line 113 of the `.aux` file, not of your source file.  Try trashing the auxiliary files and recompiling.

Comment: Ooohh, the .aux. Didn't notice that :\

Comment: I don't have a     .aux file. I just have the     main.tex, a     .bib file, and then a series of .png images

Comment: @AdamWoolsey The .aux is created by TeX. Try removing it, and compile again. If it doesn't work, read Heiko's answer carefully, it'll point you to the problem.

Comment: Is this different if I am using Overleaf? I cannot see how to remove any .aux file

Comment: I used the recompile from scratch function in overleaf and all is working well thanks for your help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
./main.aux:113:
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.113 ... find region of proportionality}{{1}{10}}
```

The error is caused by line 113 in the `*.aux` file, not the `.tex` file.
The end of line 113 looks like a label definition with an entity (section, equation, figure, ...) numbered with `1` on page 10.

The label name in `\label{...}` must survive a `\csname ...\endcsname`. Thus, my suspicion is that the label name contains stuff (non-ASCII letters, ...) that breaks in the `.aux` file.

Comment: I have not created a .aux file. Is this something that is created automatically?

Comment: I used the recompile from scratch function in overleaf and all is working well thanks for your help!!

Comment: @AdamWoolsey The `.aux` file is created automatically. For example, it stores the contents for the `\label` commands. Then, at the next LaTeX run, the `.aux` file is read and `\ref` can now use the label data from the `.aux` file.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar error:

`<...> aux ! Missing \endcsname inserted. <to be read again> <...>`

Heiko Oberdiek's answer led me to suspect the characters in the following line were the cause:

`\bibliographystyle{~/.TeXfiles/C-APAbibliographystyle.bst}`

This is itself a reference to a symlink (`.TeXFiles`) in my home directory.

When I instead used a symlink just one directory up from my .tex file (to make the symlink I ran: `ln -s ~/<...>/TeXfiles/C-APAbibliographystyle.bst C-APAbibliographystyle.bst` in the directory above my .tex file), and not the path-in-TeX-file method (`\bibliographystyle{~/.TeXfiles/C-APAbibliographystyle.bst}`), my new line became simply:

`\bibliographystyle{../C-APAbibliographystyle.bst}`

Fixed.

I don't know if it was the `~` or the `.` or if there was something about sending TeX on that particular path to the file (to my home dir, then through a symlink to the target file), but I'm using the same file in the same location, only via a cleaner symlink path.